Problems textbook for special relativity
I'm learning special relativity using "Special Relativity in General Frames, From Particles to Astrophysics" (the book by Gourgoulhon), however, there are no problems in the textbook. Can anyone provide me with references for special relativity problems following his book?

I can only recommend textbooks and resources that I've used, but here are some suggestions:

"Special Relativity" by A.P. French is a classic introductory text that I've found quite helpful. It provides clear explanations of the fundamentals of special relativity and includes a good number of problems at the end of each chapter. The problems range from straightforward applications to more thought-provoking questions, which might complement the theoretical approach in Gourgoulhon's book.

"Spacetime Physics" by Edwin F. Taylor and John Archibald Wheeler is another book I highly recommend. It's known for its intuitive approach and use of spacetime diagrams to illustrate concepts. The book offers numerous exercises throughout the chapters, with answers to many of them provided at the back. This can be particularly useful for self-study and for testing your understanding as you progress.

"Introduction to Special Relativity" by James H. Smith offers a logical progression of topics with an emphasis on problem-solving. Each chapter concludes with a set of problems that reinforce the material covered. I've found the problems to be well-crafted and helpful for gaining a deeper understanding of the concepts.

"Problem Book in Relativity and Gravitation" by Lightman, Press, Price, and Teukolsky is a comprehensive collection of problems that spans both special and general relativity. The special relativity section contains a wide range of problems, from basic to quite challenging, along with detailed solutions. This book could serve as a valuable supplement to Gourgoulhon's text by providing practical problems to work through.

David Morin's "Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions" might seem out of place, but it includes a thorough chapter on special relativity. The problems are particularly challenging and come with detailed solutions, which can be very beneficial if you're looking to deepen your problem-solving skills.

Online Resources: Universities often provide course materials online. For instance, the MIT OpenCourseWare offers lecture notes, assignments, and exams for courses on special relativity. These materials include problem sets that you might find useful. Here's a link to one such course: MIT OpenCourseWare - Introduction to Special Relativity.


I hope these resources help you find the practice problems you're looking for. Working through a variety of problems is a great way to reinforce the concepts from Gourgoulhon's book and gain a more comprehensive understanding of special relativity.
